# Why is this the notation for taking derivatives?

Tags: derivatives, notation

For a function like $y = x^2$, the derivative is $dy = 2x\ dx$ and its formally rewritten as $\frac{dy}{dx} = 2x$. This makes sense to me logically because its saying the change in y over the change in x is 2x. How come when my teacher tells us to take the derivative of a function he will write it like this: $[\frac{d}{dx}] y=x^2$? To me, I see this as "change over change of x". I know this notation means take the derivative of the function, but what does $\frac{d}{dx}$ mean exactly?

Comment: $\frac{d}{dx}$ is an [operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_(mathematics)#Calculus)

Comment: It emphasizes that differentiation is an *operation* (or *operator*) on functions: you feed a function into $d/dx$, and it spits out another function. In other words, $d/dx$ is itself a function; its domain is the set of differentiable functions (on some subset of the real numbers), and its range is the set of functions that are derivatives of differentiable functions.

Answer (score 2):

The notation has no meaning beyond "take the derivative with respect to $x$" and should not be interpreted literally.  The idea is that formally if you "multiply" $\frac{d}{dx}$ by $y$ you get $\frac{dy}{dx}$, but this is is really just a "notational joke" since it does not really make sense to separate the $d$ from the $y$ like this.  You should think of $\frac{d}{dx}$ as a single indecomposable unit that just means "take the derivative with respect to $x$".

Comment: It **does** have a meaning, simply not that of a product or quotient. $\frac{d}{dx}$ is an operator, here it is "a function which maps functions to functions." $\frac{d}{dx}$ is the "name" of that operator.